# What does Meteor do to my Javascript scopes when using the object tag to include a file?

Tags: svg, meteor

I am looking at meteor for an application which uses interactive SVG files included using the object tag.

I have a running prototype using static html/js/SVG files, where I can click an entity in the SVG and have a Javascript belonging to my html page get executed.

But when I adapt this prototype to be published with meteor something happens to the Javascript scopes, and the result is I can't find the html page Javascript functions from within the SVG anymore.

Basic structure of the meteor version is as follows.

app.html:

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mySVG" class="container">
    <object data="test.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
    </div>
</body>
```

test.svg (placed in the /public folder):

```
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:se="http://svg-edit.googlecode.com" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>networktest</title>
    <g>
    ...graphics...
    </g>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("click", sendClickToParentDocument, false);

    function sendClickToParentDocument(e)
    {
        if( window.parent.foo)
                window.parent.foo( e.target );
            else
                alert("Bar!");
    }
    </script>
</svg>
```

app.js:

```
function foo( target ) {
    // ... do stuff ...
}
```

Now in the meteor version I get the "Bar" alert, not the call to foo().
I have placed a breakpoint in the .js that defines the foo() function, and it gets called on page load, so that's OK. But apparently it does not end up in the same place as when I run using static files.

How can I find it from inside the SVG?

Comment: Is the app.js file also placed in the public/ folder? Otherwise meteor will change its scope to the app file, and it won't be added to the global scope.

Comment: Also, you could try this notation foo = function () {...}

Comment: I have app.js next to app.html in the top meteor application directory. Moving it to a .js file in public seems futile, these js files are not loaded by Meteor afaiks. IF as you say "the scope is changed to the app file", is there a way to get at it?

Comment: I believe Meteor wraps each of your JS files in an IIFE, so functions declared like `function name(args) {body}` and variables declared with `var` are inaccessible from outside that file. You could declare it as a true global using `foo = function() {...}` (no `var`) like boulaycote suggests.

Comment: OK, I have RTFM (http://docs.meteor.com/#namespacing) a bit better and now I see what is going on... (And bouylacote, I will happily cred you if you make your answer a proper answer not just a comment :-) )